# Set permanent Environment variable using Command Prompt

Tags: cmd, environment-variables

i have an unzip.exe file. i want to register it to environment variable such that when ever user type unzip in his command prompt he/she can use unzip.exe file.
I what to do this using Command prompt.
how should i do this.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You're looking for the `setx` command, built into Windows 7 or available on older versions with the Resource Kit.

Comment: Yes something like setx
i have tried 'setx path C:\mypath'
but above code replacing  existing path values
at the same time i what a command to remove this path from environment variable

Comment: If you want to append a directory to the path, you need to include the current `%PATH%`: `setx path ^%PATH^%;C:\mypath`.

Comment: %PATH%: setx path ^%PATH^%;C:\mypath it is now working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a quick and different method and will add unzip.exe to an existing part of the path.

```
copy unzip.exe "%windir%"
```

Comment: `del "%windir%\unzip.exe"`  That will remove it, when it is not in use.